# How to make folder unremoveable but not its content?

Tags: centos, permissions, samba

I have folder that i want to use for Samba with this structure

```
 FolderA
   |-----SubfolderA 1
   |-----SubfolderA 2
   |-----SubfolderA 3
   |-----FileA 1
   |-----FileA 2
   |-----FileA 3
```

Now I want to make *FolderA* to be unremoveable but I want to keep its content `rwx` permission. I already try `chattr` but it can't keep `rwx` permission on those subfolders and files.

For Example `chattr +i FolderA` will give *FolderA* immunity but I can't do anything inside *FolderA*, I want to still be able to do `rwx` inside *FolderA* after giving *FolderA* immumity.

I'm planning to use *FolderA* for Samba in CentOs 7

Comment: Not quite sure what you’re asking. `FolderA`’s removability is determined by the mode of its parent directory. If you are using Samba to share at the level of `FolderA` you aren’t exposing its parent directory to scrutiny, therefore there is no method by which `FolderA` would be removable via the Samba share.

Comment: @bxm yeah i should have more clear, i mean the `FolderA`, `SubfolderA` are samba folder so actually `FolderA` itself is inside a folder.

Comment: Sorry still don’t get it, maybe add more detail to your question.